# NetLogo: Is there a way to sort parametrs automatically In a new Behavoiurspace experiment?

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to automatically sort new experiment's settings in Behaviorspace? for example by following naming conventions or creation order.

I tried different combinations with different naming but I could not see a pattern in created experiment file(there might be one, because it usually creates the experiments in the same order). Usually I create the experiment, then sort the settings in another program and paste them back into NetLogo. This could be a good feature for grouping parameters in the final csv file.

Following shows a sample of parameters for a new experiments. I used first, second or third to show the order they created. Rest are just created incrementally.

```
["_0003" 50]
["_000" 50]
["_000Forth" 50]
["_000Second" 50]
["_000First" 50]
["_0099" 50]
["_0002" 50]
["_0001" 50]
["_0004" 50]
["_000Third" 50]
```

Comment: Have you looked to see if the order matches the order the sliders and switches are given in the `.nlogo` file? If so, you might be able to control the order in BehaviorSpace by editing the order in the file. (Just guessing.)

Comment: Thanks @Seth Tisue. I will give it a try.